# AngularJS / Jasmine undefined is not a constructor

Tags: angularjs, firebase, jasmine, firebase-authentication

I got error message like below. I cannot find a solution.
Similar service mock is passed. But I don't know why it causes error.

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) AppBarCtrl $scope.signOut should call firebaseAuth.$signOut FAILED
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'firebaseAuth.$signOut()') in app/scripts/controllers/appBar.js (line 19)
signOut@app/scripts/controllers/appBar.js:19:26
test/spec/controllers/appBar.js:46:21
loaded@http://localhost:8080/context.js:151:17
```

These are my controller and test code.

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('authApp')
  .controller('AppBarCtrl', function($scope, $location, $mdSidenav, firebaseAuth) {
    $scope.toggleSidenav = function() {
        $mdSidenav('sidenav').toggle();
    };

    $scope.signOut = function() {
        firebaseAuth.$signOut();
        $location.path('/');
    };
  });
})();
```

mdSidenav is worked well but firebaseAuth service mock isn't worked.
When `firebaseAuth.$signOut();` is called in Controller code, it causes error.

```
describe('AppBarCtrl', function() {
  beforeEach(module('authApp'));

  var mdSidenav, firebaseAuth;

  beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
    mdSidenav = {};
    mdSidenav.toggle = jasmine.createSpy('toggle');
    $provide.factory('$mdSidenav', function() {
      return function(componentId) {
        return mdSidenav;
      };
    });
  }));

  beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
    firebaseAuth = {};
    firebaseAuth.$signOut = jasmine.createSpy('$signOut');
    $provide.factory('firebaseAuth', function() {
      return function() {
        return firebaseAuth;
      };
    });
  }));

  var $controller;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  describe('$scope.toggleSidenav', function() {
    it('should call $mdSidenav.toggle()', function() {
      var $scope = {};
      var controller = $controller('AppBarCtrl', { $scope: $scope });
      $scope.toggleSidenav();
      expect(mdSidenav.toggle).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
  });

  describe('$scope.signOut', function() {
    it('should call firebaseAuth.$signOut', function() {
      var $scope = {};
      var controller = $controller('AppBarCtrl', { $scope: $scope });
      console.log(firebaseAuth);
      $scope.signOut();
      expect(firebaseAuth.$signOut).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add that service first with controller's instance

```
describe('$scope.signOut', function() {
it('should call firebaseAuth.$signOut', function() {
  var $scope = {};
  var controller = $controller('AppBarCtrl', { $scope: $scope,firebaseAuth:firebaseAuth });
  console.log(firebaseAuth);
  $scope.signOut();
  expect(firebaseAuth.$signOut).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

});

Comment: Thank you! It works. But I have 1 question. Why mdSidenav is worked even if I didn't add mdSidenav service to controller?

Comment: because it is associated to scope i.e $scope.toggleSidenav and you are injecting scope with your controller whereas firebaseAuth is not.